# Using two tables. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: sql, join, union

I want to create an activity feed system and my feeds (statuses) and friends are in different tables in my database. How do I connect them so that the logged in user can only receive feeds from their friends.

```
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM status WHERE author='(friend of logged-in user)' AND type='a'
**UNION** 
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1='$user' AND accepted='1' OR user2='$user' AND accepted='1' 
";
$query = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $user1 = $row["user1"];
    $user2 = $row["user2"];
    $accepted = $row["accepted"];
    $statusid = $row["id"];
    $account_name = $row["account_name"];
    $author = $row["author"];
    $postdate = $row["postdate"];
    $postdate = strftime("%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p");
    $data = $row["data"];
    $data = nl2br($data);
    $data = str_replace("&amp;","&",$data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $statusDeleteButton = '';
    if($author == $log_username || $account_name == $log_username ){
        $statusDeleteButton = '<span id="sdb_'.$statusid.'"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" onmousedown="deleteStatus(\''.$statusid.'\',\'status_'.$statusid.'\');" title="DELETE THIS STATUS AND ITS REPLIES">delete status</a></span> &nbsp; &nbsp;';
    }

    $feedlist .= '<div id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="flipwrapper pin">
        <div class="picture">
        <header class="img-btm">
            '.$postdate.'</b><br />
            20 <a href="#">cmts</a>&nbsp;255 <a href="#">likes</a>&nbsp; '.$statusDeleteButton.'
        </header>
        <a href="status_frame.php?id='.$statusid.'"><img id="bound" src="'.$data.'"/></a></div></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: We don't know what your tables look like. And you should pinpoint more where the trouble is (it seems related to SQL, rather than PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want a UNION here, but a subquery, more or less like this:

```
SELECT * FROM status 
WHERE author in (
        SELECT whateverfieldshouldmapfromfriendstoauthor FROM friends 
        WHERE user1='$user' AND accepted='1' OR user2='$user' AND  accepted='1' 
    ) AND type='a'
```

And some general tips:

- developing your queries straight in your scripting language (in this case php) is a very bad idea.  Use a tool that allows you to develop queries, run them and inspect the result sets.  There are tons of those, like MySQL's own [Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/) and [Squirrel SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)
- be very careful about SQL injection problems (if your `$user` variable is provided by the request, you are).  The best way to avoid SQL injection problems is by using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: Firstly, thank you! I'm in the midst of testing that out. However, I get an error that says: 

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:...\home.php on line 32

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:...\home.php on line 33

And those lines are the ones that say:
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

I'm lost as to what to insert in the 

WHERE author in (
        SELECT [HERE] FROM friends 
  
Thanks again!

Comment: It's the field from the friends table that contains the values the column author in status can take.  Maybe first run the subquery separately as `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user1='$user' AND accepted='1' OR user2='$user' AND  accepted='1'`, it should be obvious what column contains the values you want to find the status' author column.

Comment: Okay thank you so much by the way. The last thing I can't seem to figure out is, I combined two fields (user1 and user2) because those represent the friend request sender and receiver so the logged in user could be either one. So the code is: SELECT * FROM status 
WHERE author in (
        SELECT (user1 + user2) AS user3 FROM friends 
        WHERE user1='$log_username' AND accepted='1' OR user2='$log_username' AND  accepted='1' 
    ) AND type='a' 
"; (CONCAT wouldn't work for me btw). Anyway, it keeps giving me the feed from all users. What am I doing wrong there?

Comment: @sienna hard to say without knowing the details of your implementation, but if it works it's probably correct :-)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I posted too quickly so it was incomplete. The question is complete now.

Comment: You should study the output of `SELECT (user1 + user2) AS user3 FROM friends WHERE user1='$log_username' AND accepted='1' OR user2='$log_username' AND accepted='1'` because the values produced there decide what the outer query will return, I'm guessing that that query is returning more or less the entire content of friends (some issue with the where clause probably).  Once you fix the problem you have there everything should work as intended.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for your time by the way. You were extremely helpful and I really appreciate that. (: Have a good day/night♥

Comment: @sienna you're welcome.  Good luck with your project!  and ps: don't forget my remark about sql injections, you really should take that risk very seriously, and it's infinitely better to fix it now that after someone trashed your database!.